# Multiline regex to match string after space-separated data

Tags: regex, pcre, lookbehind

My goal is to achieve multiline unicode-aware string cleaning using regex.

I've started from this regex, which has no lookbehind limits:

```
(?<=[[:blank:]]).*
```

Then, I've found way to limit lookbehind as follows:

```
(?!.{20,})(?<=[[:blank:]]).*
```

It works on some cases, but not really stable([link](https://regex101.com/r/jwmtqo/1/)) because string length is not predictable.

Also tailing comma is undesireable, but I've not figured out how it could be removed with regex, because due to it's unpredictable manner(see testcase).

How do I create propely limited lookbehind for this task? I'm using boost(pcre)-style regex.

Test cases:

In

```
РПÑАВÂРßÛÑ ÛÑРВßР ÛÑÛÑАÑÛ, 11.22 Ø.Á.
ÛÑРВЛÛÑВ ÛÑßВßДÛÑВßЛ РИÐРÛПÑÑВÛ 11.22 Ã.Ö
ВßÑÛВÂЛÛÑВ ÛÑВÂÛÑВЛß ßРßÂРÑВЛРÛÐßРВ, 11.22 Â.Ö.
ÛÑВÛÑВ ÛßÛßРÑВßРÐ ßТАÛ, 11.22 Ã.Ö.
РÐÑАВПРßÛÑ ÛÑРВßР ÛÑÛÑАÑÛ, 11.22 Ø.р.
ÛÑРВÂÛÑВ ÛÑßВßДÛÑВßÂ РÂПРÛПÑÑВÛ 11.22 Ø.Á.
ВßÑÛВДЛÛÑВ ÛÑВЛÛÑВЛß ßРßЛРÑВЛРÛЛßРВ 11.22 Ø.Ö.
ÛÑВÛÑВ ÛßÛßРÑВßРÐ ßТАÛ, 11.22 Ï.Á.
```

Out

```
РПÑАВÂРßÛÑ ÛÑРВßР ÛÑÛÑАÑÛ
ÛÑРВЛÛÑВ ÛÑßВßДÛÑВßЛ РИÐРÛПÑÑВÛ
ВßÑÛВÂЛÛÑВ ÛÑВÂÛÑВЛß ßРßÂРÑВЛРÛÐßРВ
ÛÑВÛÑВ ÛßÛßРÑВßРÐ ßТАÛ
РÐÑАВПРßÛÑ ÛÑРВßР ÛÑÛÑАÑÛ
ÛÑРВÂÛÑВ ÛÑßВßДÛÑВßÂ РÂПРÛПÑÑВÛ
ВßÑÛВДЛÛÑВ ÛÑВЛÛÑВЛß ßРßЛРÑВЛРÛЛßРВ
ÛÑВÛÑВ ÛßÛßРÑВßРÐ ßТАÛ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also match those unwanted parts:

```
\s*[,\d].*
```

then replace them with nothing (or remove them) in your environment.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/4rFuCC/2)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample output, I take it you need to extract any sequence of Unicode but not Latin letters (`\p{L}`) or spaces (`\s`) spreading from the beginning of the line till first character not in this class:

```
^[\p{L}\s]+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/4rFuCC/1

Comment: Sorry, but npp could not match anything with this regex and given test

Comment: Oh, Notepadd++ makes difference. It supports PCRE but in a limited fashion. Particularly, it does not support Unicode categories, including `L` - see comments to `\Pshort name,\P{name]` [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions). With NPP you may use `\w` to match alphanumerics including Unicode ones. So the regex may be rewritten as `^(?:(?!\d)[\w\s])+`.

Comment: sorry, but this regex not working either. Due to `^` it tries to match from beginning.

Comment: From beginning of every line. In my tests it returns `РПÑАВÂРßÛÑ ÛÑРВßР ÛÑÛÑАÑÛ`, `ÛÑРВЛÛÑВ ÛÑßВßДÛÑВßЛ РИÐРÛПÑÑВÛ `, etc.